# How to determine what is updating my freedns/dyndns record with my current IP (on OS X Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, networking, cron

Somehow, a while ago, I set a way to automatically update my DynamicDNS record on http://freedns.afraid.org/ with my Mac IP address.

I don't remember how I set this or where should I look to disable it, as it isn't needed anymore and I don't want the record pointing to my IP every time I get online or my public IP address changes.

So far I've tried:

- Issuing the command `grep -lr "afraid" *` in hopes to find any reference to the end-point where my record is updated (http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?record_update_token_here). I left this command running for 24 hours but seems at some point it wasn't searching anymore because the process wasn't using any system resources at all.
- Checking all launchd records, both using [lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) and opening the files on vim
- Using `crontab -e` both with my user and as root. In both cases the crontab file didn't even exist. I'm using this method, on linux systems under the same DynDNS account, and is what I thought I used on OS X as well.
- Checking if I had installed any of the programs listed on http://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/freedns.clients.php and forgot about it. Didn't find any of those apps installed or scripts running.
- Checking if this was assigned automatically when I log in on afraid.org. Doesn't seems to be the case (and wouldn't make sense) as it is not possible to create/store the record without assigning an IP address. Also logged in from my cellphone using the carrier data plan, the IP was still pointing to my computer.
- Checking my `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` for any script/command being run at some point.

So, any help or idea on where to look for the source (script/task/app/daemon/cronjob...) of the automatic update of my DynDNS record?

Comment: Is your Mac the only laptop on the network?  Did you check your router for any Ddns settings?

Comment: Yes, my Mac is the only laptop on the network. I didn't change any setting on the router and wouldn't consider this an option, as I'm connected right now at a (elder) friend's house. I just checked to be sure: there's no DynDNS service stored on the router.

Comment: Freedns.afraid.org requires username and password to update a record, so I would say it would be near impossible for the router to come already setup to your Freedns account.    If you aren't going to use the name record   on Freedns.afraid.org then just login to the Freedns.afraid.org account and delete the name record.  I use Freedns.afraid.org but only for pc based Dvr systems.  So not sure about which clients are available for Mac machines.

Comment: The credentials (user/pass) aren't necessary to update a record, I'm using a query somewhere that includes an authorization token (see the first bullet on my question). I could rotate my authentication token(s) but this include ALL records (can't cherry-pick) and I would have to configure each script with the new keys on other systems/servers using the previous tokens. Also, this wouldn't stop my machine from executing the code that is updating my records, it would just prevent the records from being updated.

Comment: Check the advanced options for your computer name in the Sharing panel of System Preferences. OS X supports "Wide Area Bonjour", which uses IETF standard DNS Dynamic Updates to push DNS record updates to a DNS server. This is different than the HTTP-based "Dynamic DNS" that most providers use, but some providers, including Dyn.com, support it as a less-publicized alternative.

Comment: @Spiff thanks, but the option "Use dynamic global hostname" is unchecked (or were you referring to something else?), just as all the Services on the Sharing settings view.

Comment: @cesalazar Yes, "Use dynamic global hostname" that's what I was referring to. That's the UI for Wide Area Bonjour. I was on mobile at the time and couldn't remember the exact labels.